# Vertical Bootstrap Nav will not fill width of CSS Grid parent element

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, css-grid

Here is a JS Fiddle of the problem for reference:
https://jsfiddle.net/ncoughlin/1fjxy230/4/

I am having an issue where I am trying to get a [vertical bootstrap nav](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#vertical) menu to inherit the width of it's parent element, which is a CSS Grid column. For the sake of troubleshooting I have put the background of the grid column to red. So I am essentially trying to get the dark gray vertical nav on the left hand side to match the width of the red Grid column.

The bootstrap nav has id `#settings-nav`

I have tried the basic stuff like adding the bootstrap class `w-100` to the nav ul or in the stylesheet adding `width: 100%;` however both of these make the menu stretch over the entire viewport instead of the parent element, which is the Grid column. It's behaving like the Grid column is not it's parent element, but using inspector I know that it is...

Please let me know where I am going wrong here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being that the `#settings-nav` was set to `position:absolute`, which makes it so that it ignores the dimensions of the parent element. Changed to `position:relative` and it works perfectly.